# Rails ruby script/server error -- no such file to load -- gdata/spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Rails ruby script/server error --  no such file to load -- gdata/spreadsheet

I have require gdata/speadsheet in /Users/me/myapp/vendor/gems/roo-1.2.3/lib/roo/google.rb

I cannot figure out how to install it.

Tried
gem install gdata_spreadsheet
gem install spreadsheet
gem install gdata

Which all seem to install, but still get

no such file to load -- gdata/spreadsheet

When

ruby script/server.

Any ideas on how to get this file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bundler for dependencies try adding the gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'gdata_spreadsheet'
```

Then use bundler to install your dependencies and start your server:

```
bundle
bundle exec script/server
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand you or you did not read my question. I was able to install gdata_spreadsheet just fine, but that did not resolve the issue. The require is for gdata/spreadsheet.